# One way request, no response

Tags: jmeter

Normally JMeter sends a HTTP request and waits for a response to measure the response time and then to send a next request.

I have a situation where they have created a HTTP endpoint to an embedded software device. But it is one way traffic only, which means I send a HTTP request, but the embedded device doesn't send a response. This is the intention and how it should work.

Is it possible that JMeter doesn't wait for the response and just sends a next request?

Comment: HTTP protocol dictates a response. Missing response is considered a failure. You can set your timeout to be small and retry to 0 so that request does not wait for too long but this will be reported as a failed request.

Comment: You can use Synchronize Timer to trigger all the requests simultaneously without waiting for the subsequent requests. Set timeout in milliseconds is 0.
Let me know if works for you :) 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it is to set a Response timeout on the HTTP Request and add an assertion to ignore response timeout.

[image]

1 second for response timeout in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

[image]

And adding a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) that ignores status and expects a Timeout:

[image]

But this is not very clean.

Comment: Thanks! Is is for me a good way to handle this specific situation

Comment: I doubt above solution will work. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam, I correct you, it works :-)

Comment: Thanks. But is this the correct way to handle above requirement?

Comment: I warned about it. If you have a better answer, you're welcome